# what to pass inside definition value while creating token issuance policiy using graph api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/policies/tokenIssuancePolicies

Content-type: application/json

{
"definition": [
"definition-value"
],
"displayName": "displayName-value",
"isOrganizationDefault": true
}

Inside definition, I am not getting what am I suppose to pass.

Comment: Put yourself in the other person's shoes. Would you understand what is in asked here? (Please also edit your question and use the `Code Sample` button to format your code)

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/tokenissuancepolicy?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties)

Example of definition given in above link:

```
"definition": [
    "{ \"TokenIssuancePolicy\":{\"TokenResponseSigningPolicy\":\"TokenOnly\",\"SamlTokenVersion\":\"1.1\",\"SigningAlgorithm\":\"http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256\",\"Version\":1}}"
  ]
```